# Cannot Testing with Static Responses

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm trying to implement an InAppBilling in my Android app.

I'm almost there, but there is still one part missing.

I've followed the documentation (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Subs) and replicate the logic used in the sample app provided by Google.

I have this application published in alpha mode, with one test account and an integrated product (subscription) created.

```
String payload = "";
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Settings.this, SKU_PREMIUM, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,null, 1000, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

If `SKU_PREMIUM` variable is the real product id defined in google console, everything is fine. I windows appears in my application telling me to buy the subscription, and its price. However, given that I do not have a visa card associated to my test account, I cannot proceed. Thus, I'm trying to use Static Responses.
However, if I change `SKU_PREMIUM` to `"android.test.purchased"`, I'm given an error saying `The item you requested is not available for purchase.`.
And even if I change reserved code to `android.test.canceled`, `android.test.refuned` or `android.test.item_unavailable` the outcome is the same.

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Got it! The problem here is that you cannot use reserved product ids on subscription testing. They are only suitable for "normal" purchases.

Comment: So, how does one test the subscriptions?

Comment: If you have a solution you can post it here as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use reserved product ids on subscription testing. They are only suitable for "normal" purchases. For subscriptions you to use the right subscription id defined by you in google play settings page. You should:

1. Upload an apk to store (it can be in alfa or beta testing);
2. Be the application tester (the email should be different from the developer email);
3. Have a credit card associated to your test account.

If you have this setup, you won't be charged by Google. Note that in-app subscriptions auto-renew every 24h.

As far as I know, there is no easy way to test the android in-app billing. You really have to follow theses steps.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that subs cannot be tested this way. It is such a pain to work with Android InApp